# Failed to run constructor: TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'addPlugin'

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to add a macaddress plugin into my project. but what i got is
"Failed to run constructor: TypeError: Object # has no method 'addPlugin' at file:///android_asset/www/javascripts/cordova-2.0.0.js:297 " from the logchat. Can anybody kowns how can I deal with it to make my plugin work.
I am using plugin from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/MacAddress. 
In my application.js files, I wrote

```
    function onLoad() {
        console.log('Init reached');
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {

        console.log('Starting up...');
    //  navigator.app.overrideBackbutton(true);
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

    }

function getMacAddress(){
    /*get macaddress*/
    var networkInterface = {};
    // Get network interface   
    networkInterface = window.plugins.macaddress.getMacAddress();

    console.log(networkInterface.mac);
    $("#wifi_mac_address").text(networkInterface.mac);   
}
```

In index.html file, I wrote

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/application.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/MacAddress.js"></script>

   </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
         ...

          <li data-theme="c">
                 WiFi mac address:
                 <span id="wifi_mac_address">
                 123
                 </span>
          </li>

         ...
    </body>
</html>
```

I started phonegap and Jquery mobile for just 3 weeks.Please give me some advices to solve it if you know.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming your problem is at line 297. That's all I can tell you because you don't give us more information ...

Hint: code would help

Comment: I dont see where you call you`re getMacAdress() Function. The error could drop by calling the (phonegap-related-) function before onDeviceready()(= Phonegap is ready).

Comment: It would help others if you feedback on answers, please accept the answer or place a remark that it did not solve your question. And in case you solved it: share the solution to the world!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scripts are wrongly placed, when you trying run your mac adress function you haven't loaded your MacAdress.js, to fix your problem you need to place your scripts like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/MacAddress.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you to point it out. I have already solved the problem the same way you said. I am new to jquery mobile. :)